# <xsl:for-each> loop for find the first coborrower

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on a project and I facing difficulties on a  loop where I have to get the first co-borrower on the application. 
I am using

```
<xsl:for-each select="LOAN_MEMBER_INDIVID/LOAN_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_DATA/LOAN_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION[LOAN_MEMBER_INDIVID_ROLE_ON_APPLICATION='Co-borrower /Bashkekredimarres']">
</xsl:for-each>
```

But every attempt that I try it gets only the first role on the application which is Borrower. any help?

Comment: Can you edit a question to show a sample of your XML, and the output you expect please? Thank you

Comment: As i can understand you are checking in [] same element either you have to use . in predicate or delete element name just before starting predicate. For more please update your question with input XML where we can see the structure.